# Using Hexadecimal to represent -1(10 in two's complement on 9bits

Tags: binary, hex

I'm using two's complement and -1(decimal) is converted to 1111 1111(TwoCom) on eigth bits. The first bit says that the number is negative and when I convert to hex I receive a FF by result.

Is correct?

But I need to know how I can represent -1 (decimal) in hex on 9 bits.

I guess that this would be 1FF ... but I'm not sure.

Any help?

Comment: With signed binary/hexadecimal the most significant bit is negative and the rest are positive no matter how many bits you have.  With 9 bits 100 = -256 and FF = +255 so total = -1.  However, how are you holding 9 bits? If you are storing it in a 16-bit variable, bit 9 is not the most significant and is positive.

Comment: I have a state transition diagram and I have to make the chronogram with hexadecimal values. 
When I was validating this one threw an error, I have assumed that the error was the -1 in hexadecimal because I wrote the number with 16bits, FFF.

It solved, thanks Tony :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A two's complement number is defined as a 1's complement number + 1. So if you have 9 bits available, and you original number is decimal 1, i.e. `000000001` binary, the 1's complement is `111111110` binary, and the 2's complement is `111111111` binary, which represents -1 decimal.
So, you are right, this is `1FF` hex.